# (Since + past simple) or (Since + present perfect)?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

The explanation taken from my grammar book says

> In a setence which includes a time clause with **since**, we generally
> prefer a past simple verb in the time clause and a present perfect
> verb in the main clause. The time clause refers to a particular point
> in the past.
>
> - **Since** Mr Dodson **became** president unemployment **has increased**. (*rather than ... has become...*)

However, there's an exercise in another unit that says otherwise. This is a sentence in a problem in the unit and the **words in bold** is the key answer:

> **Correct the present perfect continuous verbs using either the past simple or present perfect.**
>
> It's remarkable to think that **since** 1950 influenza (1) *has been
> claiming* (**has claimed**) more than 50,000 lives in this country,
> and in 1957 alone around 6,000 people (2) *have been dying* (**died**).

As the book explains, then why not:

> It's remarkable to think that **since** 1950 influenza **claimed** more than 50,000 lives in this country,
> and in 1957 alone around 6,000 people **have died**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tenses, there is never a die-hard rule which applies in every situation. I think the best way you can get used to different tenses is really just to see them in lots of different examples and you try to gain a natural feeling for them.

But, it's important to note that the present perfect describes actions that are finished. In the first example, it is implied that Mr Dodson is still the president (or still the president at the time in which the sentence is concerned) so you use the past simple. However in the second example, those 50,000 lives are dead and done, the action there has terminated and hence the present perfect is preferred.

Comment: but if the action of being dead is terminated you could use the past simple(died), the present perfect relates to the  present (up to now); the action can still happen or has recently finished .So I find a bit strange to use have been died and not died , I don't see the relevance to the present because it happens in 1957. The only present relevance is the enonciation . The sentence is said now

Comment: @user5577 My answer refers to the verb in the main clause, you can use "died" in the dependant clause. The action in the main clause is influenza killing all those people.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some confusion about what is the time clause in the second example.

> It's remarkable to think that since 1950 influenza has claimed more than 50,000 lives in this country, and in 1957 alone around 6,000 people died.

Here the time clause is "since 1950". That's all. Nothing more. (Note: it might be more correct to call it a prepositional phrase, but it's clearly the case that "since 1950" is doing the work of a time clause in that sentence.)

There are two independent clauses:

> since 1950 influenza has claimed more than 50,000 lives in this country

Here the present perfect is used because it describes something that happened in the past continuing up until today.

> in 1957 alone around 6,000 people died

Here the simple past is used because 1957 is a long time ago.

In the first example, a time clause, something that has a subject and a verb, is used in place of a date to emphasize an event which the writer/speaker believes to be relevant to the main clause.

> Since Mr Dodson became president unemployment has increased.

The writer thinks that Mr. Dodson's administration has had an adverse effect on unemployment. By the way when did Mr. Dodson become president? Let's say it was 2012. Then the sentence could be written equivalently as

> Since 2012 unemployment has increased.

but then it would not be clear to the audience that unemployment increased because Mr. Dodson is a bad president.